# How do I install gdb on a Macbook M1 to use it in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, installation, gdb, apple-m1

I am quite new to the programming world and am trying to learn some coding on Eclipse by following a guided self-study book.
For the course I should use Eclipse with gdb for debugging. Unfortunately I cannot get gdb working; I managed to follow the steps in this file ([https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/macmingweclipse/allexperimental/mac-gdb-install.html](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Epattis/common/handouts/macmingweclipse/allexperimental/mac-gdb-install.html)) and everything worked, excpet for gdb to relaunch after quitting. So now I am quite clueless about how to proceed?

I also tried installing it via Homebrew, but when executing
`brew install gdb`
I get the message
*gdb: The x86_64 architecture is required for this software. Error: gdb: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.*

I know that there are issues with gdb on Mac with M1 chip, but is there any way to resolve this? My computer knowledge isn't very good as for know, so I probably need quite a step-by-step guidance.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

GDB has not been ported to MacOS for the M1 (AArch64) architecture.  The `lldb` debugger is available for MacOS on M1, you could consider using that debugger.

Comment: Oh, I see. Do you mind me asking how lldb is installed and how I can make Eclipse use that debugger?

Comment: I don't use either MacOS or lldb, so I can't help there.  Sorry.